# python executor spawn tasks from done callback (recursively submit tasks)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to submit further tasks from result of a task that was done:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(my_task)
    def callback(future):
        for another_task in future.result():
            future = executor.submit(another_task)
            future.add_done_callback(callback)
    future.add_done_callback(callback)
```

but I'm getting:

> RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after shutdown

What's the best way to make the executor hold for the callback? A semaphore?

Ideally the solution should transfer well if `ThreadPoolExecutor` is replaced with `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is guaranteed to max out processing at any given point. The use of `sleep` is not that elegant but this is the best I have so far.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    pending_tasks = 1
    future = executor.submit(my_task)
    def callback(future):
        nonlocal pending_tasks
        for another_task in future.result():
            pending_tasks += 1
            future = executor.submit(another_task)
            future.add_done_callback(callback)
        pending_tasks -= 1
    future.add_done_callback(callback)
    while pending_tasks:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `callback` is executed in a separate thread. Therefore, when your callback logic starts executing, there's a high chance the main loop will leave the context manager shutting down the `Executor`. That's why you observe the `RuntimeError`.

The easiest fix is running your logic sequentially.

```
futures = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    futures.append(pool.submit(task))

    while futures:
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            futures.remove(future)

            for new_task in future.result():
                futures.append(pool.submit(new_task))
```

Note that this code might cause an exponential submission of tasks to the `Executor`.

Comment: Does `concurrent.futures.as_completed` block? Can that cause a delay in submitting new tasks somehow?

Comment: It blocks until one of your `future` objects is ready. Which is anyway what you have to do as the jobs to be submitted are provided by the results of the `future` itself.

Comment: consider we start with 1 easy task and 2 two hard tasks, the easy one gets released first and splits into 50 new easy tasks, but we don't reach them before we're done with the remaining 2 hard tasks (no matter how many threads we have).

Comment: I mean - we might reach them, but not the ones they spawn. Essentially we're doing something that is a bit like BFS on the tasks graph, and not necessarily throttling out the threads/processes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Nevertheless, the logic above is pretty simple. The `concurrent.futures.as_completed` blocks until one of the given `futures` is ready. No matter which as the order does not matter. Therefore the above logic is correct: it waits until there's something more to be done. When new tasks come (as result of a completed future), it asynchronously schedule them to the `pool`. You can't do otherwise as your problem has a sequential nature: the new tasks depend on the old ones to complete.