# Adobe Analytics API cannot schedule new futures after shutdown

Tags: python, api, azure-functions

My problem is: I can´t list the VRS of my subscription because when I call the getReportSuites method it fails showing the error:

```
api2.getReportSuites(token) : cannot schedule new futures after shutdown
```

It's very courious because in my local environment it works and in fact I retrive the data, but when I upload the code and run it into an Azure Functions premium it stops working and gives this error.

What I've tried:
I´ve tried to change credentials and refreshing them in case it was a credentials issue but it happens the same thing. I've also changed the token itself but it seems that it is not related with that.
My code;

```
   tkn="";
    try:
        
        tkn=api2.Analytics(cids);#this works 
    except Exception as inst:
        logging.error ("Error in invocar api2.Analytics(ret) get token : " +str(inst));

    vrsid="";#retrieve the vrs
    
    try:
        vrsid=tkn.getReportSuites();#here pops out the error
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error ("Error in   api2.getReportSuites(ret) : " +str(ex));
```

This was woriking one month ago, why has it stopped right now?
Links I followed:
[python executor spawn tasks from done callback (recursively submit tasks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879070/python-executor-spawn-tasks-from-done-callback-recursively-submit-tasks)

https://bugs.python.org/issue40093

https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/285

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding in my requirements.txt file the "futures==3.1.1" library. I've uploaded the cocde to the azure functions container and worked again. But I don't understand why it stopped working suddenly.